# How to use Shopify Liquid's "sort" filter to sort by product availability or quantity?

Tags: sorting, pagination, shopify, liquid

How can I use Shopify's Liquid's

`{{ assign sorted_array = some_array |`***`sort: 'some_property_of_array_items'`***`}}`

filter to sort by `variants.inventory_quantity` in an effort to push sold out / out of stock items to bottom/back pages of paginated collection?

### What I've Tried

I've tried:

```
{% assign collection_products = collection.products | sort: 'variants[0].inventory_quantity' %}
```

as well as:

```
{% assign collection_products = collection.products | sort: 'variants.first.inventory_quantity' %}
```

aaaand:

```
`{% assign collection_products = collection.products | sort: variants.first.inventory_quantity %}`
```

and many other variations, but the best result is typically:

`Liquid error: comparison of ProductDrop with ProductDrop failed`

My original attempt to push down all sold out products to the bottom (in a nice, clean way) was to try this:

```
`{% assign collection_products = collection.products | sort: 'available' %}`
```

But that leads to the same error, though this time I strongly suspect its because liquid can't run comparisons with boolean values, `true` or `false`.

Am I doing something wrong for the syntax, or is there some other way to push all products to the back pages of a paginates collection?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way I know of to do this in pure liquid. 
One way would be to create an app (private is fine -- you could run it from your local machine) and sort the collection. You could put that on a server and sort it nightly. Then the native sort of the collection would have products with the most inventory first.

Comment: I may need to do this anyway for other custom apps, some requiring a DB.  What stack do you recommend for this purpose -- would I just get an AWS server and use PHP/MySQL?

Comment: Any stack will do.  Use one you are familiar with.  I use Node/Express and Heroku primarily.